# system x11 default problems

Tags: debian, desktop-environment

I have Debian 9 stretch, and I have problems with the desktop environment.

System x11 default have problems when I tried to start the session. everything freeze. I don't know what to do. but I think by changing it would run correctly

How can I change it?